# Sending an email in C# .net

Tags: .net

I have the following code to send an email:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
client.Send(myfrom@email.com, "myreceipient@email.com", "test", "test");
```

Now because I'm sending it from my own work PC, I have IIS 5.0 setup and obviously most email servers on the recipients side will assume this could be spam as its coming from a ADSL IP. So I authenticate the code above using:

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(myEmailHere, myPasswordHere);
```

But it still won't send to some clients. Is there a way around this? Eventually this code will sit on a RackSpace server, how could/would I set it up to make sure the recipient servers do not think its spam?

Answer (score 5):

Having your email not flagged as spam is a huge and challenging topic.

The first, best rule is:

- Sent from a static IP address, not one part of a recycled pool (like from a DSL/Cable provider, virtual server host, etc).  Check to see if the previous owner used it for spam by sending test emails to your test accounts at hotmail, yahoo, gmail, etc.
- Never send spam from that address (including anything that more than a few people might flag as spam, even if you think it's not)

If you're serious about sending a significant amount of legitimate email and not getting flagged as spam, you have a lot to learn beyond what you can get from SO.  Here are a few resources to get you started down that path:

[Avoid Blacklist Blues](http://www.clickz.com/3381621)

[Avoid Being Blacklisted](http://www.howtoforge.com/how_to_avoid_being_blacklisted)

[How to Avoid Blacklists](http://www.ehow.com/how_5075040_avoid-blacklists.html)

Comment: Nice points. I tend to route all our email traffic through third party smtp servers. Gmail, Jango, Yahoo, etc. are all going to be better than you or I at keeping server IP's off the blacklists.