# How to send an email using C#?

Tags: c#, email

Looking in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384532/sending-an-email-in-c-sharp-net) it uses the following to send emails:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
```

Is that the easiest approach to use when sending mails from a console application. Outlook is installed in the machine that I'd like to send from - would it be overkill adding a reference and using that namespace?

Apologies for a slightly vague question but my experience is within VBA and in when the VBA resides in Excel I've always used Outlook but in SQLserver I use the following so was wondering if there's something similar in c#:

```
msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
```

I am using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for `SmtpClient` as Outlook Interop is not trivial for C# beginners. If you need a fast solution, use `SmtpClient` first and spend some spare time on trying to implement the Outlook solution - just for the sake of learning how to do things ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`SmtpClient` is the way to send an email from your code, if that's where you want the work done. If you want a more server-centric approach, you can use the SQL stored procedure approach.

If you want a proprietary solution that requires you install Outlook where ever you want to run your program, then you can go the Outlook route. I don't recommend it, however.

Comment: interesting - I'd not even thought of using a stoed proc and firing it out from the server. I've already got some c# code for running procs from the server so I could use that.

Answer (score 0):

> Best

You didn't tell us your criteria for selecting the best.

> `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` is that the easiest approach

It is very easy to use. Interop with Outlook is not easy at all.

> would it be overkill adding a reference and using that namespace?

I think so. Unless you need Outlook-specific features, doing this doesn't add any value to your project (it actually subtracts value).

> I use the following so was wondering if there's something similar in c#:

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`

Comment: you pretty much guessed my criteria for "best" - ease of use. Although I was fishing for opinions on what people prefer to use and what works best for them as I've never sent a mail from an app built using c#.